# How can I develop a plugin for Kibana?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, react-redux, kibana-7

I am really a beginner in ELK stack. I want to learn a plugin building for Kibana. I see their documentation for plugin building (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/development-plugin-resources.html)

But the thing is, it's not enough for me or I can't understand it properly. I want to customize the Kibana dashboard with some other functionalities I want. I want to build the plugin by ReactJs in front-end. If anybody has any resource or any example codes to share it would be a great help for me. I am using Kibana and ElasticSearch both version 7.4.2

Comment: is there any update? if you successfully created the plugin could be please share it?

Answer (score 1):

This might be an old question, but since I am facing the same issue, so maybe someone else could use this answer.

I found this presentation by Elastic for how to build you own Kibana plugin, it is an old one, they are working on Kibana 5 I guess, but could be a good starting point for someone.

https://www.elastic.co/elasticon/conf/2016/sf/how-to-build-your-own-kibana-plugins

I have also found this article that is more recent and the author uses ELK 7

https://chunkbytes.com/how-to-create-a-plugin-for-kibana/

Comment: this is not working `https://chunkbytes.com/how-to-create-a-plugin-for-kibana/` can you please update your answer

Comment: I don't know where is that article, but you can check Elastic's documentation for building Kibana plugins https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/external-plugin-development.html